# Dynamic Pivot in Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

```
exec proc_TestPivotCol 'SectionID','StudiedBy'
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[proc_TestPivotCol]
@ColHeader nvarchar(10),
@RowHeader    nvarchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @q as NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols ='
select STUFF((SELECT  '','' + QUOTENAME('+@ColHeader+') 
                    from Section
                    group by SectionID
                    order by SectionID
            FOR XML PATH(''''), TYPE
            ).value(''.'', ''NVARCHAR(MAX)'') 
        ,1,1,'''')'
      execute(@cols)



 set @q =' SELECT StudiedBy, '+@cols+'
            from  (select  '+ @RowHeader+','+ @ColHeader+' from ##tempF)
             X
            pivot 
            (
                count(CDFID)
                for ' + @ColHeader+' in ('+@cols+' )
            ) p '
execute(@q)
print(@q)                   
END
```

what is the syntax wrong of this procedure
their is an error:Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'select'.
@cols return [B],[C],[H] but i dont understand what wrong in @q

Comment: Does it print the `$q`? If so could you post that one?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with your execute(@cols) ? It looks like that's where it is starting to go  wrong for you.

Comment: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'select'

Comment: result of @cols its good but when i use it in @q cannot take the result([H],..) it take it it as string select STUFF((SELECT  ',' + QUOTENAME(SectionID) 
                    from CDFSection
                    group by SectionID
                    order by SectionID
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

Comment: i want to create dynamic pivot table with dynamic columns in sql server inside stored procedure

Comment: your execution of @cols will not be usable in your execution of @q if that's what you're trying to achieve? Because that'll cause your incorrect syntax near select